# Is it possible to display text after pressing a button using if or v-if?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am trying to figure out a way to display a text after a button is being pressed.

Favourably it should work with a dropdown button with multiple options and a different text for each option selected. Multiple texts would be nice but right now i just want to get it to work with only one text, so that when i select option 1 it displays text 1 and if option 2 is selected it should display text 2.

Now i want to get this to work with xslt but i first want to have it working in either html or svg.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <label for="Fehler">Wählen sie die zutreffende Fehlermeldung aus:</label>
  <select name="Fehler" id="Fehler">
    <option value="Falscher_Bauteil">Falscher Bauteil</option>
    <option value="Falsch_dimensioniert">Falsch Dimensioniert</option>
    <option value="Falsch_angeschlossen">Falsch angeschlossen</option>
    <option value="Falsch">Falsch</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  
  <p v-if="value == 'Falscher_Bauteil'">Falscher Bauteil verwendet!</p>
  <p v-if="value == 'Falsch_dimensioniert'">Der Bauteil ist falsch dimensioniert!</p>
  <p v-if="value == 'Falsch_angeschlossen'">Der Bauteil ist falsch angeschlossen!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using Visual Studio Code and this was the code where i thought it would work.

My idea why it is not working would be because i need to declare a new variable for each different option but as far as i know to declare a variable you need the script tag and then it all needs to be inside of the script tag but then the dropdown button wont work.

Another thought of mine is that the

is not the right one for this purpose. But i dont really know any other way to display text other than the  but i want it to be a static text.

As you probably have guessed by now i am relatiely new to this so i would appreciate any help.

Comment: why are you using v-if ? That is Vue JS directive and will not work unless you use Vue js.

Comment: Are you using the JavaScript framework Vue? Your code contains HTML only, the JS code is missing. With Vue, you could use `v-model`on the select and set the text of the paragraph accordingly. But you don't really know how to use Vue yet, do you?

Comment: I highly encourage you to check my answer, it is pure js. And will teach you how to do this without any framework.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers i will look into the things you told me. And yes i am new to vue.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Display .innerHTML text after changing a "dropdown" select element?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

<script>

function HideText(){
var Info = document.getElementById("Info");
Info.style.visibility="hidden";
}

function ShowText(select){
 if (select.value=="Visible"){ Info.style.visibility="visible"; }
 else { Info.style.visibility="hidden"; }
}
</script>

 <body onload="HideText()">
<select  onchange="ShowText( this );"> 
<option>Hidden</option>
<option>Visible</option>
</select>

<div id="Info">
More Information regarding JavaScript
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, if you need to select multiple text then you will need checkboxes not select inputs.
Also if you need user selection to be shown on load, then remove first option which I added and call handleSelect on load by passing the current selected value.

```js
const selectTextDom = document.querySelector('.select-text');
const textSingleDom = id => document.querySelector(`*[data-text-id="${id}"]`);
const textAllDom = document.querySelectorAll('.text-js');

const hideAllText = () => {
    textAllDom.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('text--show'));
}
const showSingleText = textId => textSingleDom(textId).classList.add("text--show");

const handleSelect = (e) => {
    const textId = e.target.value;
  hideAllText();
  showSingleText(textId);
}

selectTextDom.addEventListener('change', handleSelect)
```

```css
.text {
  display: none;
}

.text--show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <select class="select-text">
    <option selected disabled>select text</option>
    <option value="text-one">text one</option>
    <option value="text-two">text two</option>
    <option value="text-three">text three</option>
  </select>

  
  
  <p data-text-id="text-one" class="text text-js">text one text one text one text one text one text one text one</p>
  <p data-text-id="text-two" class="text text-js">text two text two text two text two text two text two text two</p>
  <p data-text-id="text-three" class="text text-js">text three text three text three text three text three text three</p>
```